# Is the class of all limit ordinals a proper class?

Tags: set-theory, axioms

Let $\mathbf{Lim}$ denote the class of limit ordinals. Is it true that $\mathbf{Lim}$ is a proper class? How does one prove that?

Comment: Welcome to MSE,  quick tips : 1. It is recommended on this website to add your own attempts when asking a question so that others can help you. 2. Please as all the context related to your question, inorder to have a clear one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class of limit ordinals cannot be a set. Its union would be a set of *all* ordinals, and then the Burali-Forti paradox obtains a contradiction.

The class wouldn't qualify as an ordinal even it if were a set, because an ordinal is supposed to be transitive. But, for example, the class of limit ordinals contains $\omega$ but not its element $42$, so it is not transitive.